# SQL show only data after this date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display data on and after this date using this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(mm, [closedate]) AS [Month],
    COUNT([opp]) AS 'Won Opportunities', SUM([actual]) AS  'Value'
FROM  
    [dbo].[tableName]
WHERE 
    [person] = 'Name'   
    AND Month([CreatedOn]) = 2015-08-01
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm, [closedate])
```

But it does not seem to be working.

This is the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''2015-08-01'' to data type int.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the data to a specific month or do you want everything after the specified date?

Comment: Hey @jpw, that month and after.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all rows after a specific date you want:

```
where CreatedOn >= '2015-08-01'
```

this would get you everything after August 1st.

However, if you only want rows from August then you want

```
where month(CreatedOn) = 8 -- or where month(CreatedOn) = month('2015-08-01')
```

In any case the date literal needs to be in single-quotes like so: `'2015-08-01'` instead of `2015-08-01`.

Answer (score 0):

The Month() function returns an integer. Change to `Month([CreatedOn]) = 8`.

You probably also need to include an expression in your WHERE clause to only return rows on or after whatever date you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
SELECT
DATEPART(mm,[closedate]) AS [Month],
COUNT([opp]) AS 'Won Opportunities', SUM([actual]) AS  'Value'

FROM  [dbo].[tableName]
WHERE [person]= 'Name'  
AND [CreatedOn] >= Cast('2015-08-01' as date)
/*  AND [CreatedOn] >= '2015-08-01' -- also try with this  */

GROUP BY 
DATEPART(mm,[closedate])
```

Comment: It returns all the months?

Comment: I have updated my above answer based on question's comments. please try and let me know if any concern.